# failed to compile dataflow sample

Tags: dataflow, google-cloud-dataflow

I tried the Google sample dataflow but I get the following error when I run maven install as described in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started?hl=fr&_ga=1.125650562.926983999.1433230333):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project
> google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project
> com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all:jar:manual_build:
>
> Could not find artifact
> com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:jar:tests:manual_build
> in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
> the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
> debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors
> and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR]
> [Help 1]

Comment: Help!!! Does somebody encounter the same problem?

Comment: What was the command that you executed to get this error? Also, did you run "mvn clean install" as per the "To download and install the Google Dataflow SDK for Java and examples from GitHub:" on https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/getting-started

Answer (score -1):

In fact I did mvn clean install and always get the error. It seams that the jar google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk cannot be build.

Comment: Are you still encountering this issue?